# Plone update Collection Filter

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

Can I update a filter from a Plone Collection (plone.app.collection)?

I have a Collection with thhose filters:

```
portal_type = Project
review_state = published
```

With an BrowserView (Form) I want to extends this filter a follow:

```
portal_type = Project  
review_state = published
+  
subject = ['test', 'foo']
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please clear this question a little: you have configured portal_type and review_state filters in the Plone collection interface and you want to extends applied filters programmatically?

Comment: Yes, the Collection shows all published Projects and within a Form the user can add more filter criterias, after send I want to extend the original filter with the parameters set by the user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very simple thanks to recent changes done on plone.app.collection (be sure to use plone.app.collection 1.1.2 or newer).

Having the collection loaded in your code as `collection` (or probably `context` if you are running your view on the collection itself) if you call...:

```
results = collection.results()
```

...`results` will contains all contents found by collection itself, so with you `review_state` and `portal_type` filter applied.

But you can use the `custom_query` param as follow:

```
results = collection.results(custom_query={'Subject': ['test', 'foo']})
```